# split int into folders

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

i need to crete some http_rewrite :

i will have request `some.url/123456`

and i have to do something split this url into:

```
/{directory1}/{directory2}/{directory3}/{directory4}/123456.jpg
```

where

```
directory1 = 1
directory2 - 12
directory3 = 123
directory4 = 1234
```

so it will be:

```
/1/12/123/1234/123456.jpg
```

so the number must be slitted into few folders

could you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root, try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((((([0-9])[0-9])[0-9])[0-9])[0-9]+)\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ /$5/$4/$3/$2/$1.$6 [L]
```

You can add a `,R=301` in the square brackets if you want to redirect the browser so that the URL in the address bar shows `http://some.url/1/12/123/1234/123456.jpg`

If you want to put these rules in server/vhost config, add a `/` after the `^` in the rewrite rule's regular expression.